# Multi-Objective Optimization in genetic Algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, heuristics

I am very new to metaheuristic optimization.
I am trying to solve a problem using genetic algorithm.

I have 4 outputs:

1. over-population
2. under-population
3. over-time
4. under-time

My objective is to have all the values to 0(minimization problem).
My fitness function is sum of all.

```
function fitness(){
 return over-population + under-population + over-time + under-time
}
```

But this is not good, as one objective is different from other. So I want to scalarize one objective(like population) to another.

But I am facing problem in applying. I am not getting the starting point for this.

Can you please tell where should I start from?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would use an actual multi-objective optimization algorithm with multiple fitness functions instead of the single scalarized one you posted.
I'd suggest you look into NSGA-II, which is a widely used evolutionary multi-objective optimization algorithm.

If you really insist on using a single objective optimization algorithm with a scalarized approach, you have to come up with some kind of weights. I don't think there is a universally appliable approach for that.

If there is a maximum error for each objective, you could use that to normalize each objective, so they all have the same weight, but even that might not match what you want because of potentially differnetly distributed values. You could also assign weights and adapt them through trial and error.

On a side note, if over-population and under-population are complementary (you cannot have both at the same time), regardless of your optimization approach you should use a single error for the population, which would be the absolute difference between the ideal and the actual (over or under) population size. Same goes for over-time and under-time, if applicable.